# Java FX not recognizing KeyCode.UP or KeyCode.Down when up and down arrows pressed (MacBook Pro 18 - Mojave 10.14.5 )

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently learning Java, and am working on event driven programming with Java FX.  This program makes a circle, and increases its size via a few different methods (Buttons, Mouse Buttons, Up and Down Arrow).

The buttons, and mouse clicks work fine, but the up and down arrows do not.  It seems that when I press them, no KeyCodes are received.  I have tried changing this to other keys, and it works fine.

I actually copied this program out of the book for practice, and it is identical to my code...

I am using a MacBook Pro 18, on Mojave 10.14.5.  Java 10, IntelliJ Community Edition 2019.1.

Code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
package testing2;

import javafx.application.Application; import javafx.geometry.Pos; import javafx.scene.Scene; import javafx.scene.control.Button; import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode; import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton; import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane; import javafx.scene.layout.HBox; import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane; import javafx.scene.paint.Color; import javafx.scene.shape.Circle; import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControlCircleWithMouseAndKey extends Application {
    private CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //hold 2 buttons in an Hbos
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button btEnlarge = new Button("Enlarge");
        Button btShrink = new Button("Shrink");
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btEnlarge, btShrink);

        //Create and register button click handlers
        btEnlarge.setOnAction(e -> circlePane.enlarge());
        btShrink.setOnAction(e -> circlePane.shrink());

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(circlePane);
        borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
        borderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Change Circle");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        //Register the mouse clicks enlarge and shrink
        circlePane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                circlePane.enlarge();
            } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                circlePane.shrink();
            }
        });

        //Register keys to englarge and shrink
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                circlePane.enlarge();
            } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                circlePane.shrink();
            } else {
                System.out.println(e.getCode());
            }
        });

    } }

class CirclePane extends StackPane {
    private Circle circle = new Circle(50);

    public CirclePane() {
        getChildren().add(circle);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void enlarge() {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() + 2);
    }

    public void shrink() {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() > 2 ? circle.getRadius() - 1 : circle.getRadius());
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used 'scene' to register the key presses. Shouldn't that be 'borderPane' (it all depends on focus I guess)?

Comment: I did try borderPane as well, with the same results

Comment: How about 'borderPane.requestFocus();'? (after 'primaryStage.show();')

Comment: Worked, thank you!   Any idea why it didn't work with the scene?  When I switch it to a different key, I could increase or decrease the size.

Comment: I have no clue. I tried your code (win10-64b) and it works fine without any modification, so I'm in the dark when it comes to your problem on the Mac. Anyway, glad I could help :)